# Telegram Bot on Flask issue

Tags: python, flask

I am developing a pet project of mine. The telegram bot sends the hash or file it receives to the VirusTotal site for verification, and then sends back a detailed verification report. However, when I send it a file not yet checked by the VT site, it sends me an 'An error occurred while checking the file on VirusTotal'.

I think the problem is that it doesn't have time to check the file when it receives a GET request. To fix this, I decided to create a condition where, when `response_code = 0`, the application waits 10 seconds and sends the request again and so on until it gets another `response_code`. But I am still facing this problem. Please help me, I just started learning PYTHON and it's a whole new experience to ask for help here!

```
# Import required modules
import requests
import hashlib
import time
from flask import Flask, request

# Set bot token and VirusTotal API key
BOT_TOKEN = ''

# define the VirusTotal API key
VT_API_KEY = ''

# Create Flask app
app = Flask(__name__)

# Function to handle incoming messages
def handle_message(message):
    chat_id = message['chat']['id']
    # Check if message contains a document
    if 'document' in message:
        file_id = message['document']['file_id']
        file_url = f'https://api.telegram.org/bot{BOT_TOKEN}/getFile?file_id={file_id}'
        response = requests.get(file_url)
        if not response.ok:
            send_message(chat_id, 'An error occurred while downloading the file')
            return
        file_path = response.json().get('result', {}).get('file_path')
        if not file_path:
            send_message(chat_id, 'An error occurred while retrieving the file path')
            return
        file_url = f'https://api.telegram.org/file/bot{BOT_TOKEN}/{file_path}'
        # Download file content
        response = requests.get(file_url)
        if not response.ok:
            send_message(chat_id, 'An error occurred while downloading the file content')
            return
        content = response.content
        # Compute file hash
        file_hash = hashlib.sha256(content).hexdigest()
    # If message doesn't contain a document, assume it contains a hash
    else:
        file_hash = message['text']
        # If hash is not of length 32 or 64, compute hash of hash value
        if len(file_hash) not in (32, 64):
            file_hash = hashlib.sha256(file_hash.encode()).hexdigest()
    # Build VirusTotal URL for file report
    vt_url = f'https://www.virustotal.com/vtapi/v2/file/report?apikey={VT_API_KEY}&resource={file_hash}'
    # Query VirusTotal for file report
    vt_response = requests.get(vt_url).json()
    while True:
         vt_response = requests.get(vt_url).json()
         if vt_response['response_code'] != 0:
            break
         time.sleep(10)
    # Check if file report was retrieved successfully
    if vt_response.get('response_code') == 1:
        positives = vt_response.get('positives')
        total = vt_response.get('total')
        permalink = vt_response.get('permalink')
        # If file is clean, send response indicating clean status and include detailed report URL
        if positives == 0:
            response_text = f'The file has been checked on VirusTotal and is clean ({total} scans). Here is the detailed report: {permalink}'
        # If file is malicious, send response indicating malicious status and include detailed report URL
        else:
            response_text = f'The file has been checked on VirusTotal and is malicious ({positives}/{total} detections). Here is the detailed report: {permalink}'
    # If file report couldn't be retrieved, send error response
    else:
        response_text = 'An error occurred while checking the file on VirusTotal'
    # Send response message to user
    send_message(chat_id, response_text)

# Function to send message to Telegram
def send_message(chat_id, text):
    url = f'https://api.telegram.org/bot{BOT_TOKEN}/sendMessage?chat_id={chat_id}&text={text}'
    requests.post(url)

# define a route to receive incoming Telegram messages
@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def receive_message():
    message = request.json['message']
    if 'document' in message or ('text' in message and len(message['text']) in (32, 64)):
        handle_message(message)
    return 'OK'

# run the Flask app
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=5000)
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`/file/report`](https://developers.virustotal.com/v2.0/reference/file-report) endpoint you are currently using doesn't scan a file. It just searches for a pre existing report using the file hash. If one is not found in the first request, you should use the endpoint [`/file/scan`](https://developers.virustotal.com/v2.0/reference/file-scan) to send the file to be scanned. Then you'll be able to request the report.

I also noticed you are using the API v2. If feasible, [you should consider migrating to the API v3](https://developers.virustotal.com/reference/api-v2-v3-migration-guide#why-use-vt-api-v3)